# Confuse about pure in applicative functor

Tags: haskell

I have following example with `pure` function:

```
Prelude> :t pure ((+1) 1)
pure ((+1) 1) :: (Num a, Applicative f) => f a
```

What is above the concrete type of `f` wrapped `a`?

For example, the `f`(structure) is here Maybe:

```
Prelude> pure ((+1) 1) :: Maybe Int
Just 2
```

and what is the structure of:

```
pure ((+1) 1)
```

?

**The second example:**

```
Prelude> :t pure ((+1) 1) :: [Int]
pure ((+1) 1) :: [Int] :: [Int]
```

Why does the GHCi show the type twice, namely `:: [Int] :: [Int]` not only `:: [Int]`?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. As to the second: GHCi simply echoes the expression you asked about (`pure ((+1) 1) :: [Int]`) and then follows it with the inferred type (which is boring in this case, since you've already written out explicitly what you want the type to be, leading to an exact duplication of the signature).

Comment: I edited my post. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `f` and `a` are both type variables. There is no concrete type. It will use whatever type is required by the surrounding context.
2. When you type `:t EXPR`, ghci prints the type as `EXPR :: TYPE`. The first `:: [Int]` is part of the expression you typed; the second `:: [Int]` is the type computed by ghci.